# bash batch image resize

Tags: bash, image-resizing

How change this string:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | while read i; do convert "$i" -resize 50% "${i%%.jpg*}_tn.jpg"; done
```

to make  tn_FILENAME.jpg files, not FILENAME_tn.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | while read i; do [[ "${i##*/}" =~ ^tn_ ]] || convert "$i" -resize 50% "${i%/*}/tn_${i##*/}"; done
```

You mean like this?

`${i%/*}` is the filename stripped of everything following the last dash (so the dir in which the file is located).

`/tn_` adds the tn_ prefix to the file, and

`${i##*/}` strips everything from the file before the last dash (so it's the filename).

Paste these three together and you get your result.

Comment: yes. but i have error "convert.im6: unable to open image `tn_./sets/testl/test-123.jpg.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638."

Comment: Try this: `"${i%/*}/tn_${i##*/}"`

Comment: No problem, you need me to clarify the solution?

Comment: Add `grep -v tn_*` when you want to run the command again after new files in the folders.

Comment: Good point, although that grep matches any path not containing "tn".